# Checking username and password for python (Tkinter)

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

I am creating a login system in python using Tkinter and have been able, write to the text file with a username and password in my Register window. However, inside of my Login window, I am not sure how to go about checking whether or not the username or password entered is correct or not?

```
#Register window code
    self.newNameEntry = Entry(self.master,
                     highlightcolor="grey",
                     highlightthickness=2,
                     highlightbackground="#FF4500")

    self.newNameEntry.place(x=245, y=100)

    self.newPasswordEntry = Entry(self.master,
                     highlightcolor="grey",
                     highlightthickness=2,
                     highlightbackground="#FF4500")

    self.newPasswordEntry.place(x=245, y=140)
def signUp(self):
    text = self.newNameEntry.get() + " " + self.newPasswordEntry.get() + "\n"
    with open("LoginDetails.txt", 'a')as f:
        f.write(text)
#Login window code
   self.nameEntry = Entry(self.master,
                     highlightcolor="grey",
                     highlightthickness=2,
                     highlightbackground="#FF4500")

   self.nameEntry.place(x=245, y=100)

   self.passwordEntry = Entry(self.master,
                     highlightcolor="grey",
                     highlightthickness=2,
                     highlightbackground="#FF4500")
   self.loginBtn = Button(self.master,
                   text="Login",
                   fg="white",
                   bg="#282828",
                   command = self.openHubWindow)#calls the function
   self.loginBtn.place(x=298, y=192)
   self.passwordEntry.place(x=245, y=140)
def openHubWindow(self): #Where I want the login checks to happen
          self.master.withdraw()
          root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
          hub = HubWindow.TheHub(root2)
```

Comment: open file and read line-by-line and compare with login and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set yourself up with some variables that can grab the values out of the Entry boxes when you want

```
self.userNameVar = StringVar()
self.passwordVar = StringVar()
```

Then add these as parameters when creating the entry widgets

```
self.nameEntry = Entry(self.master,
                       highlightcolor="grey",
                       textvariable=self.userNameVar,
                       highlightthickness=2,
                       highlightbackground="#FF4500")

self.passwordEntry = Entry(self.master,
                           highlightcolor="grey",
                           textvariable=self.passwordVar,
                           highlightthickness=2,
                           highlightbackground="#FF4500")
```

For example you could bind  and Left-click to check for the validness of your user name and password

```
self.master.bind('<Return>', lambda e: self.checkValidUsernamePassword())

self.master.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: self.checkValidUsernamePassword())
```

Then you write your callback function where you actually go about checking these username / password combos

```
def checkValidUserPass(self):
    user = self.userNameVar.get()
    attemptPassword = self.passwordVar.get()

    try:
        realPassword = self.users[user]
        if attemptPassword == realPassword:
             self.actuallyIsValidUser()  # They are good - do something

    except KeyError:  # That user name is not in our dictionary of users
        self.invaidUser()

def invalidUser():
    print("That is a bad user.")
    # Turn this into a message box, or other UX
```

But you will need to add this to your **init**:

```
def __init__(self):
    # .....
    self.users = {}  # empty dictionary
    self.loadUsers() # and load the user base
    # .....


def loadUsers(self):
    # Loadup all of the usernames and passwords into a dictionary
    with open("LoginDetails.txt", 'r') as f:
        for row in f:
            user, password = row.split(" ")
            self.users[user] = password # Puts this user & password into the dictionary
```

Note: You used a space as the deliminator on names/passwords (bug because some names have spaces).  Try using another symbol like a : and pop that symbol into where you write the user/pass and in the split() above

Comment: Hey thank you for your input however after much testing I found that there was an issue with the realPassword = self.users[user] when entering the username and password. For example if username was Happy and password was Sad. The self.users[user] would be {'Happy': 'Sad\n'} and therefore would make realPassword equal this. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Hmm, looks like you just need to strip the newlines ("\n") off of the real passwords:

Answer (score -1):

Try to only post your code which is in question ;)

Treat it as normal - get the user input from a text box, assign it to a variable, then check that for the username, and then add a second and box repeat that process for your password. So in Pseudo code:

```
PASSWORD = "password"
USERNAME = "user"
ACCESS = FALSE

if INPUT_ONE = PASSWORD then
    if INPUT_TWO = USERNAME then
        ACCESS = TRUE
    end if
end if
```

Comment: whoa .. this isnt python... (is this vbasic? oh nm pseudocode i see)